# Media Recorder API in android produces files which cannot b played

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to use the mediarecorder api to record audio. What I have done, but can't get a playable audio output. It always says unsupported format and no audio plays.

1. sought and attained both storage and record permission (in manifest and in code), so no errors this side.
2. Initialized mediarecorder as follows:

   ```
   myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        String fullPath = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Util.VOICE_NOTES_FOLDER_NAME).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp";
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(fullPath);
   ```
3. Then I prepared the audio and started like this:

```
  

   

    try{
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            }catch (Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "PREPARE FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            myAudioRecorder.start();
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

4. I am using a touch event (touch up) to stop the recording, and I call this stop recording method when touch on the record button is up:

```
    private void stopRecording(){
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.reset();
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder = null;
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "recording finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

4. The file is saved successfully, there is a file size above zero, format is in .3gp, but the audio won't play. It gives unsupported file format in various media players.

note: I am testing this on a real device running android 11.

Comment: The extension of your file is .3gp. Audio format is something different. And you did not even tell your audio format.

Comment: the audio encoder format AMR_NB is the format used in google docs, so I used it too.